# matplotlib: match legend colour to patchCollection colour

Tags: python, matplotlib

I overlay patches over an image with the (simplified) following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imread
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Arrow
import numpy as np

def plotFeatures( patches, colours, legends, str_title, colour_scale ):

    fig = plt.figure(); ax = plt.gca()

    p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Spectral_r'), alpha=0.9)
    p.set_array(np.array(colours))
    ax.add_collection(p)
    p.set_clim(colour_scale)
    fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax, fraction=0.015)
    plt.xlabel(str_title)
    plt.legend(handles=patches, labels=legends, bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .2), mode='expand', ncol=3, loc="lower left")
    # ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xlim([0,100])
    ax.set_ylim([0,100])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('Spectral_r')

    # simplified data structure for example
    allweights = [  {'name': 'Feature 1', 'mean': 2.1, 'x': 60, 'y':30},
                    {'name': 'Feature 2', 'mean': 3.0, 'x': 10, 'y':40},
                    {'name': 'Feature 3', 'mean': 2.5, 'x': 30, 'y':20} ]

    KPD_patchList  = []
    KPD_colourList = []
    KPD_legendList = []

    for w in allweights:
        KPD_patchList.append( Circle( (w['x'], w['y']), w['mean'] + 5 ) )
        KPD_colourList.append( w['mean'] )
        KPD_legendList.append( '{:s} ({:.2f})'.format( w['name'], w['mean']) )

    plotFeatures( KPD_patchList, KPD_colourList, KPD_legendList, 'myFeatures', [0, 3] )

    plt.show()
```

That results in:
[image]

However the patches in the legend do not have the correct colour.

The problem I have is that I set the colour for the PatchColelction p, but plt.legend() does not accept a PatchColelction for handles and I have to feed it with the patches that do not contain colour data.

I tried to add colour data to the patches directly with  `facecolor=my_cmap(w['mean']` when I call Cricle, as:

```
for w in allweights:
        KPD_patchList.append( Circle( (w['x'], w['y']), w['mean'] + 5, facecolor=my_cmap(w['mean']) ) )
        KPD_colourList.append( w['mean'] )
        KPD_legendList.append( '{:s} ({:.2f})'.format( w['name'], w['mean']) )
```

but then the colours are not equaly scaled as in the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with your second attempt, except that your data is not normalized correctly for the colormap.
When you try to get a color value from a colormap, you need to provide a value in the range `[0-1]`. To make things easier, I often use `matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable` ([link to documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html?highlight=cmap#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable)) which handles this transformation automatically.

To solve your problem I modified the function `plotFeatures()` like so:

```
def plotFeatures( patches, colours, legends, str_title, colour_scale ):

    fig = plt.figure(); ax = plt.gca()

    p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Spectral_r'), alpha=0.9)
    p.set_array(np.array(colours))
    ax.add_collection(p)
    p.set_clim(colour_scale)
    fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax, fraction=0.015)
    plt.xlabel(str_title)

    # generate legend
    # create a `ScalarMappable` object with the colormap used, and the right scaling
    cm = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=p.get_cmap())
    cm.set_clim(colour_scale)
    # create a list of Patches for the legend
    l = [Circle((None,None), facecolor=cm.to_rgba(mean_value)) for mean_value in colours]
    # add legend to plot
    plt.legend(handles=l, labels=legends, bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .2), mode='expand', ncol=3, loc="lower left")


    # ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xlim([0,100])
    ax.set_ylim([0,100])
```

[image]

Comment: I had to `import matplotlib`, and I changed the variable `l` for `legend_handles`, as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) naming convention. Otherwise perfect.